# Assertion error while running test with LatchCountDownAndCallRealMethodAnswer from RabbitMQ

Tags: junit, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I have a listener test, where i post a message in a parallel thread and check with LatchCountDownAndCallRealMethodAnswer if the all were processed successfully. Running the test alone, it works perfectly, however if you run all other tests together, it fails because it failed to leave the counter at zero, but the listener received and processed the message normally. Does anyone have any ideas?

My Test Class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@RabbitListenerTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class EventListenerTest {

    EventListener eventListener;

    @Autowired
    protected RabbitListenerTestHarness harness;

    @Autowired
    private EventStoreRepository repository;

    @SpyBean
    private DomainEventPublisher publisher;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        DomainRegister.setDomainEventPublisher(publisher);
        eventListener = this.harness.getSpy("eventListenerId");
    }

    @Test
    public void storeEventsListenerTest() throws Exception {

        LatchCountDownAndCallRealMethodAnswer answer = new LatchCountDownAndCallRealMethodAnswer(1);
        doAnswer(answer).when(eventListener).storeEvents(any(BalanceReserved.class));

        publisher.publish(new BalanceReserved("12233", 150.0, BigDecimal.ZERO), "");

        assertTrue(answer.getLatch().await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));

        verify(eventListener, times(1)).storeEvents(any(BalanceReserved.class));
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        DomainRegister.setDomainEventPublisher(null);
        reset(eventListener);
        repository.deleteAll();
    }

}
```

Error

```
java.lang.AssertionError
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have other tests using the same queue, you need to shut down the application context for each test so the test's listeners are stopped. By default, the Spring Test framework caches the application context for reuse. This will cause other tests to "steal" messages.

Add `@DirtiesContext` to each test class that uses `@RabbitListener`s, to tell the test framework to shutdown the context.

Comment: Even if i forget the event editor in the other tests, will this influence the rabbit this test?

Comment: event publisher*

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "forget". But if you have other tests where you are using a `@RabbitListener` that consumes from the same queue as this one, those tests' containers (if still running) might (are likely to) get this test's message. You should always add `@DirtiesContext` to any test case that starts a listener container, so the container is stopped after the test ends.

Comment: Sorry, it's "mock" not to forget lol, translator sucks xd, but i understood how it works, thank you Gary.